# Show $x=0$ and $x=1$ are the only integer solutions

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I'm trying to show that the only solutions to $x^2-x+1=y^2$ are when $x=0$ and $x=1$. All I can think of is completing the square gives $x^2-x+1=(x-\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4}$, which is clearly not a perfect square. Does this suffice? Should I use induction?

Comment: Why clearly?  It's a perfect square when $x=0$ or $1$.

Comment: Would I prove that those are the only solutions using induction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that we have (for positive $x$):
$$
(x-1)^2\leq x^2-x+1\leq x^2
$$
so your expression lies between two consecutive squares. Now you just have to check for equality on either side, and you will have found all cases.

Answer (score 6):

$$x^2-x+1=y^2\\
4x^2-4x+4=4y^2 \\
(2y)^2-(2x-1)^2=3 \\
\left( 2y-2x+1\right) \left(2y+2x-1 \right)=3
$$

Answer (score 4):

Multiply by $4$ to obtain $$(2x-1)^2+3=4y^2$$ or $$4y^2-(2x-1)^2=3$$ or $$(2y-2x+1)(2y+2x-1)=3$$

And the factors are in some order either $3,1$ or $-3, -1$

The sum of the two factors is $4y=4, -4$ respectively, so $y=\pm 1$

The difference between the two factors is $4x-2=\pm 2$ so $x=0,1$

All four combinations actually work.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply by the equation by $4$ and complete the square for $x$. We have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
(2x-1)^2+3=(2y)^2 \\
(2y+2x-1)(2y-2x+1)=3
\end{eqnarray*}
So Either 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\cases{2y+2x-1=3 \\
2y-2x+1=1} \text{or}
\cases{2y+2x-1=-3 \\
2y-2x+1=-1}
\end{eqnarray*}
or 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\cases{2y+2x-1=1 \\
2y-2x+1=3} \text{or} \cases{2y+2x-1=-1 \\
2y-2x+1=-3}
\end{eqnarray*}
so  $(x,y)$ has solutions $\color{blue}{(1, \pm 1)}$ and $\color{green}{(0, \pm 1)}$.

Comment: You need to consider $-1 \times -3 = 3$ for integer solutions. Otherwise you beat me to this, and my first effort had an error. But I think this is the way to do it - multiply by $4$ to keep things integral, and use the difference of two squares.